# Add hyperlink to "title" tag text

Tags: javascript, html

I am using some Javascript to swap text from a "title" tag to a description below the large image on my page.

How can I add a link to the text that is being swapped below the large image?

Sample page here - [Sample Page](http://sdmxc.net/magic/magicscroll&magiczoomplus01.html)

**js** -

```
    function updateCaption(elm) {
    document.getElementById('captionText').innerHTML = elm.getAttribute('title');
}
```

**html** -

```
<a href="ipod-blue-large.jpg" onmouseover="updateCaption(this);" title="iPod Blue" rel="zoom-id:ipod"
```

```
<a href="ipod-blue-large.jpg" class="MagicZoom"  id="ipod"><img src="ipod-blue-large.jpg"></a><span id="captionText">Text to be swapped</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the name implies, innerHTML accepts standard HTML. So you may do this :

```
function updateCaption(elm) {
     document.getElementById('captionText').innerHTML = "<a href=somehref>"+elm.getAttribute('title')+"</a>";
}
```

Supposing you'd want to have the same href for the caption than for the image, you may do this :

```
function updateCaption(elm) {
     document.getElementById('captionText').innerHTML = 
          '<a href="'+elm.href+'">'
          + elm.getAttribute('title')
          + '</a>';
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand, do you mean add the link direct in the js, in <a href=somehref>? I don't need just one static link. I want the link to change based on what thumbnail image is hovered over, like how the text changes for this. So a link to each item page. Sorry if I am making this sound more confusing than it should!

Comment: If you put the code in the updateCaption function, it will change the link depending on the elm (you have to compute it of course).

Comment: sorry, but I still don't get it :( I'm not too sharp when it comes to js, as I'm sure you can tell... Any chance you can give me an example of what code needs to go where?

Comment: Works great, many thanks for this dystroy... Will try to be clearer in future :)